# Integrating Ember.js with a simple Sinatra backend

Tags: ruby, ember.js, sinatra

There is a lot of documentation of how to structure and create Ember.js apps with Rails as a backend. Pupular solutions are to use gems as `ember-rails` and `ember-source` or the all in one `ember-appkit-rails`.

However i'm trying to create a simple Sinatra app that handle a JSON only backend with Ember.js as the frontend.
The few resources that i found seems a little outdated, so i'm looking for simple way to do that.

So my question is:
How i integrate Ember.js with a simple Sinatra backend ??
Examples of how to do so will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [very simple repo on Github](https://github.com/cavneb/poc-sinatra-eak), that could serve as a starting point for you. Just grab the code, start the sinatra app server, and point your Ember datasource to it, like this:

```
    App.MyRestAdapter = DS.RestAdapter.extend({
      host: 'http://localhost:3000',
      namespace: 'api'
    });

    App.store = DS.Store.create({
      adapter: 'MyApp.MyRestAdapter'
    });
```

You could also look into the source of [Travis CI](https://github.com/travis-ci), as they use Sinatra (travis-api) and Ember.js (travis-web).

Comment: For a simple JSON backend, [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) is worth mentioning.

Comment: +1 For the good resources to hack on. I'll be digging on this.

Comment: That repo mentioned is funny because Sinatra depends on Rack. The Gemfile has an issue.